# How to get progressBar progression [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

Let me say that I have a progessBar, how can I know the progression of the bar without having to use a counter to see how many steps the program made.

Just for research.

Comment: WPF or Forms or ASPX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*WPF with MVVM:*

Use your `Databinding` to bind your `ProgressBar` Property `Value` to a Property of your ViewModel

*WPF without MVVM and **Forms**:*

Access your `ProgressBar` (for example with the name `ProgressBar1`) like this:

```
var currentvalue = ProgressBar1.Value;
```